# 5 to 7 seconds latency in RTMP streaming (Audio only: Wowza to Android) using Vitamio streaming Library

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, rtmp, wowza, vitamio

I am developing an Android application which is streaming from Wowza to Android device (>KITKAT). It is a **RTMP stream**. Everything is working fine. The only issue is, there is high latency (5-6 seconds) while streaming Wowza to Android device.

I have already [posted this on GitHub](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/321).

Comment: Open a vitamio issue on github.

Comment: It's already open on github. https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/321